# why button action cannot add attributes

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code

```
        protected function getActions(): array
    {
        return [
            buttonAction::make('UPLOAD')->extraAttributes(['class' => 'button'])
                ->action('kkp')
                ->requiresConfirmation()
                ->modalHeading('UPLOAD FILE')
                ->modalButton('UPLOAD FILE')
                ->form([
                    FileUpload::make('attachment')
                        ->extraAttributes(['class' => 'custom'])
                        ->label('UPLOAD SURAT PENGANTAR')
                        ->required()
                ]),
        ];
    }
```

why cannot add attributes button action on Fillament Laravel
I was try to add FileUpload components and this work after that i try to add attributes on button action but didn't work ??

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

**`ButtonAction` is deprecated!**

Please use

```
Action::make()
```

instead of

```
ButtonAction::make()
```

Comment: I have the same problem, But it still doesn't work!